# Chosen Java script plug in behavior - Shows items in list prematurely

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

We are using Chosen Javascript plugin http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ . It works great except one issue. When it loads on the page, it shows the "list box" kind of view for few split seconds in place of the Chosen plug in. It loads to the chosen plug in "view" finally. But for that few moments it looks bad with all the data showing as items in list box. For example, if we have a Chosen Plug in control linked to a list of States in US. When this page  loads, for a split second, it shows a list box (not the chosen plug in) and it shows all the items in the list (list of states etc) .. then after the page loads completely, it will render the Chosen Plug in with blank items as its supposed to.

Is there any setting I can make use of to fix this? Any work arounds? Causes? Any one encounter this before? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @OOhark can you create a fiddle?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm running in to the same issue and would love it if someone found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially set the style `display:none;` on the element and then display it once chosen loads.